# my question about my project app flutter after publishing on play store

Tags: android, mysql, flutter, dart, sqflite

i have flutter app project and i publishing him on play store but my app have like a custom scroll view contain  some pictures that i want to update them every 2 week can i update him without releasing my app and building again ??
is the database like (SQF lite)  will benefit me to this topic
the code in below contain some picture that i want update them i wrote it like example

```
Container(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
      children: [
        Expanded(child: 
          Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Text("Explore", style: TextStyle(color: textColor, fontSize: 24, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),),
            ],
          )
        ),
        IconBox(child: SvgPicture.asset("assets/icons/filter.svg", width: 20, height: 20,),)
      ],
    ),
  );
```

}

and thanks

Comment: Because it is an asset image, when you change the picture, you have to update it to the playstore again.

Comment: my friend can i using database like sqflite and updating on it without updating all of app on play store  again and is this issue you say it take so much time or its easy?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.